# How to create a "Monero Wallet" for my each user in my website?

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc

I am creating a website where I want to accept Monero as payment method. I want to create a monero wallet for my each signed up user. Like say for example, when a user logs in, his BTC, ETH, XMR and USDC all wallets are created and keys are encrypted and stored in database.
Further,only these wallets will be used if user wants to do anything on my website.
I have achieved this for BTC, ETH and USDC. Now I want to know how I can achieve this for XMR?
Anyone please help.

Answer (score 2):

Just using one wallet and a subaddress per customer is the simplest path (without knowing precisely what you're trying to achieve). You can create the new subaddresses with the wallet RPC method: [create_address](https://www.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#create_address).

Comment: Yes... How can I make this one wallet? I can generate the addresses later on. Do I need to run a full node on my server?

Comment: You can use [create_wallet](https://www.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#create_wallet) to make the wallet. Both this and the answer refer to using the `monero-wallet-rpc` which also needs to use a node (which can be yours running on the same host or someone else's remotely).

Comment: How can I access and connect a remote node?
Right now I am using the documentation here [https://github.com/PsychicCat/monero-nodejs] and getting the following error:
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:18082
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1138:16) {
errno: -111,
code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
syscall: 'connect',
address: '127.0.0.1',
port: 18082
}
is this something related to my above issue???

Comment: You have to connect to the host and port you are using for `monero-wallet-rpc`. Port 18082 is the default `monerod` zmq port, so if you want to use that port for the wallet RPC, you have to either disable zmq in `monerod` or tell `monerod` to use a different zmq port.